# how to convert numberLong to dd/mm/yyyy format in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, logic

I used date picker which is in dd/mm/yyyy format. For saving this date in mongodb database I converted this date into number Long format and save it. I want to display all records in dd/mm/yyyy format then how can I convert number long to date in dd/mm/yyyy format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this function

```
function getDateIfDate(d) {
    var m = d.match(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//);
    return m ? (new Date(+m[1])).toLocaleDateString('en-US', {month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit', year: 'numeric'}) : d;
}

console.log(getDateIfDate("/Date(1460008501597)/"));
console.log(getDateIfDate('abc'));
```